# 2 joins when querying model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have this method which returns all the categories and groups books belonging to that category

```
def self.user_categories_list
joins(:books).
select('categories.id, categories.name, count(*) AS books_count').
group('categories.id, categories.name').
order('books_count DESC')
end
```

Please excuse my question but I am unsure on how to join the users table to get all books belonging to a user by category, or could i do it by book_id belonging to a user?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: do you mean the books that belong to a specific user? In that case you just need to make this 'instance method' and call it on a user instance as `@user.user_categories_list ` and might consider renaming it just to `def categories_list`

Comment: so theres no need to call self?

Comment: with self it is a class method and it's used as  `User.user_categories_list` and it queries all the users not a specific one. In the above comment `@user = User.find(1)` 1 is the user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just had a where clause:

```
def self.user_categories_list(user)
  joins(:books).
  where('books.user_id = ?', user.try(:id) || user).
  select('categories.id, categories.name, count(*) AS books_count').
  group('categories.id, categories.name').
  order('books_count DESC')
end
```

**Note:** This code assumes that your Book model has the `user_id` attribute in its table.